# Select2 Search Icon on Search Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I use select2 with bootstrap3.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Single select boxes

How to add search icon in search field？

like this:

https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/

This is my Select2 option code:

```
$(".select2").select2({
    theme: 'bootstrap'
});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<select style="width:100%" class="select2">
    <optgroup label="Test-group">
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test2</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

inspect your html and find the css rule of input, then add background to it like:
`background: #fff url('select2.png') no-repeat 100% -22px;`

Comment: Thank you, I will check them later.